# How to connect to neo4j database from android app (with java code)?

Tags: java, android, database, neo4j, connection

I am developing one android application in java and i am using neo4j as a database for this app.

Lets, consider i will store the static cypher query in a string. Then after the user clicks on the button, i want to send this query(string) to neo4j server and then execute it on neo4j server and return the result.

My question is that, Is it possible? If yes, how can i do this ? Is there any easy/proper way to do?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question, please reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to talk directly to Neo4j, you can use either:

- [The HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/introduction/#http-api-introduction)
- [The Binary Bolt Protocol](https://github.com/neo4j-drivers/boltkit)

If you would rather use middleware, there are many many different options:

- [Java](https://neo4j.com/developer/java/)
- [.NET](https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/)
- [JavaScript](https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/)
- [Python](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/)
- [Go](https://neo4j.com/developer/go/)
- [Ruby](https://neo4j.com/developer/ruby/)
- [PHP](https://neo4j.com/developer/php/)
- [...](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/)

When building mobile apps my *personal* preference is to build a standard API in a middleware server then use HTTPS calls from the app ([neo4j-graphql-js](https://grandstack.io/docs/neo4j-graphql-js-quickstart/) has also been awesome for a couple projects), but there are enough stacks that you have the freedom to do it your way.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Can you please elaborate more on HTTP API and Binary Bolt Protocol, like how could i use them in my android application or some good resources on it ? It would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For sure. The HTTP API takes JSON and gives back JSON and therefore can be used and consumed with the built-in HTTPS libraries, or with an external library. Start here: https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/security/

Comment: Using the Binary Bolt Protocol without a library really requires understanding the protocol since it's not an industry standard. If there's any hesitation about that, I would suggest using the HTTP API instead.